# How to auto Set input values in a form when select an option?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form for example:

```
<form>
   <ul>

   <li>
   <select name="choose">
   <option value="0">1</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>

   </select>
   </li>

   <li><h2>No. Of person</h2></li>
    <input type="text" name="ref_person"id="field" value="" />

   <li><h2>earning of person:</h2></li>
    <input type="text" name="ear_person" id="field" value="" />

   </ul>
   </form>
```

so, when I choose option:1 both the input fields must be filled with no. let say, No. of person = 3 and earning of person = $5.

Comment: all that's needed is the PHP *to boot*.

Comment: @fred , could you please elaborate ? btw,Thanks for your response.

Comment: You will need JS/jQuery for that. Something like this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/17516982/

Comment: Thanks Fred, I was looking for something like this. let me try and implement it in my code. Thanks!! again :)

Comment: @fred, how to implement that method If I have two inputs ,example you shared had one input only ?

Comment: @Fred-ii-—there is no need for jQuery, or any library.

Comment: @RobG that "slash" in *"JS/jQuery"* - means an "or". and they did tag as js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   function getPerson(select) {
  var form = select.form;
  form.ref_person.value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('per');
  form.ear_person.value = select.value;
}
<form>
  <fieldset><legend>Person and earning</legend>
  <label for="personSelect">Select a person
    <select name="choose" id="personSelect" onchange="getPerson(this)">
      <option per="3" value="0">1</option>
      <option per="9"  value="100">2</option>
      <option per="27"  value="500">3</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <br>
  <label for="personNumber">No. Of person:
    <input type="text" name="ref_person"id="personNumber"></label>

  <label for="personEarning">Earning of person:
    <input type="text" name="ear_person" id="personEarning"></label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code sample that uses the onchange event to copy values to the textboxes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function selectOnChange(obj) {

         var val = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
         var text = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
         document.getElementById("field1").value = val;
         document.getElementById("field2").value = text;
      }
</script>
</head>
<body>

     <div>
         <select onchange='selectOnChange(this)' name="choose">
               <option value="100">1</option>
               <option value="200">2</option>
               <option value="300">3</option>

          </select>

      </div>
      <ul><li><h2>No. Of person</h2></li></ul>
      <div>
           <input type="text" name="ref_person" id="field1" value="">

           <ul>
                <li><h2>earning of person:</h2></li></ul>
                <input type="text" name="ear_person" id="field2" value="" />
       </div>
```

Comment: Brother, I didn't want to copy text in input fields, I want them to be filled by figures specified by me.

Comment: This figures should go in the value section to the drop down.  or use the selected index to point to a value in an array to get the values and copy them in a textbox.

Comment: yes, you are right.  Let me try this and that can be a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your question should be as well written as you can make it, including valid, semantic HTML.

Also, a question should contain the code you have tried, an explanation of what you have tried, where it's going wrong and exactly what you expect it to do, including some example input and output.

The following may help. Note that element IDs must be unique and that forms should use semantic markup (e.g. don't use a list to present it, don't put headings inside lists, use labels, group elements using fieldsets, etc.).

You can use the select element's change event to get the value and text of the selected option and display it elsewhere in the form. You can also reference form controls as named properties of the form, which is handy and more straight forward than using *getElementById*.

In the code, a reference to the select is passed to the function using *this*. Every form control has a *form* property that is a reference to the form that it's in. The rest should be easy enough to understand, but please ask if you need other help.

```js
function getPerson(select) {
  var form = select.form;
  form.ref_person.value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
  form.ear_person.value = select.value;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset><legend>Person and earning</legend>
  <label for="personSelect">Select a person
    <select name="choose" id="personSelect" onchange="getPerson(this)">
      <option value="0">1</option>
      <option value="100">2</option>
      <option value="500">3</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <br>
  <label for="personNumber">No. Of person:
    <input type="text" name="ref_person"id="personNumber"></label>

  <label for="personEarning">Earning of person:
    <input type="text" name="ear_person" id="personEarning"></label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: you made exactly the same thing I needed apart from the thing that as in your stated example ref_person field is taking its value as index of it but I want that field to be like "if select option 1 value of ref_person should be 3 and when select option 2 value of ref_person should be 9. and when option 3: valur of ref_person should be 27. " , :) Thanks!! for taking a look at my query and making blueprint of it . Thanks again for your time and contribution.

Comment: I have one more query in further process , as I fetch input values using php code , it is not working ? like                                                     <?php
$ref_person=$_POST['ref_person'];                                                        
$earn_person=$_POST['earn_person'];

$total =$ref_person * $earn_person;
$monthly = $total;
$yearly = $monthly * 12;
?> **************** I created <frame></iframe> in html page targeting that total.php file where it calculates data and reflect in html file. where as in  html file <form action="total.php"></form>

Comment: If you have another question, ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get a switch statement to work, so I did it with three if statements, but here is my solution. Fiddle with it yourself to make it as you wish.

```
<form>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <select name="choose" id="option1" onchange="relatedPrice()">
                <option value="0">1</option>
                <option value="1">2</option>
                <option value="2">3</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li><h2>No. Of person</h2></li>
        <input type="text" name="ref_person" id="field1" value="" />
        <li><h2>earning of person:</h2></li>
        <input type="text" name="ear_person" id="field2" value="" />
    </ul>
</form>
<script>
    function relatedPrice() {
        var e = document.getElementById("option1");
        var test = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

        document.getElementById("field1").value = test;
        if(test==1) {
            document.getElementById("field2").value = 100;
        }
        if(test==2) {
            document.getElementById("field2").value = 200;
        }
        if(test==3) {
            document.getElementById("field2").value = 300;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks!! mate, That seems to be a good solution too, I'll try and implement this as well :) Thumbs up!!

Comment: You have hard coded the values into a bunch of if statements. Might as well just put the values in the selectbox

Comment: Yeah, as I said, I couldn't get a switch statement to work unfortunately. That would've been better. Feel free to improve it though!

Comment: My bad, I used a template from another project. The script tag there is right underneath some other script too. Forgot to delete it. Will do it now. Thanks!