# PHP (Ajax) Paste Option from Select into input field

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, drop-down-menu

I want to paste the selected Value/option from an  drop down menu into an input field.
This have to be done without refreshing the page.
Would be best, if it works without an extra Button and the value gets posted in the input field just by clicking at it.
I think it has to be done with ajax but im not very experienced in it.

Comment: You only need to use AJAX if additional data is needed from the server.  What have you tried?  Setting a value on an `input` with JavaScript is generally pretty straightforward, and there are many examples online.

Comment: This will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516982/input-field-value-to-change-upon-selection-of-different-dropdown-menu-options EDITED: Wrong link

Comment: ok thanks, I was thinking a bit to complicated

Comment: btw you just posted the link of this question here

Comment: Oops, This is the correct link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516982/input-field-value-to-change-upon-selection-of-different-dropdown-menu-options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select id="slt">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<input id="name" value=""/>
<script>
var select = document.getElementById('slt');
select.addEventListener('change', function(){
   document.getElementById("name").value = select.value; 
});
</script>
```